# Is there a way to install/hack iMessage onto Lion/10.7?

Tags: macos, messages

My machine (MacBookPro2,2) doesn't support 10.8 and I would rather hold back on doing the upgrade (possible with hacks). So is it possible to stay on 10.7/Lion and get iMessage working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the Messages beta has ended, it is no longer offered for download on the website **however** the download link direct to the .dmg still works:

[Messages beta direct download.](http://appldnld.apple.com/MessagesBeta/041-4274.20120216.z5km/MessagesBeta.dmg)

I don't expect this to continue indefinitely.

A more permanent option would be to try and copy the Messages.app from a Mountain Lion install on another computer to your OS X Lion applications folder. Let us know if that works for you.

Comment: The Beta seems to be working. I don't have access to a 10.8 machine right now but will try that next time I have one available. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, The iMessage beta program for Lion is "closing" on Dec 14. I'm guessing the beta app will stop working at that point. Not sure about a 10.8 copied app (have not tried it yet myself).

Comment: The beta app has indeed stopped working as of Dec 14.You might still be able to get the dmg, but the service is no longer working. The app kills itself after displaying a message about downloading Mountain Lion.